# MYSQL BUG: Duplicate entry on Primary/Unique. If I insert word , Word

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, mysql-error-1062

*Hi,
I try to INSERT in my database 2 different words with PHP.*

```
word <= *is the first*

Word <= *is the secound
```

***Create Code:***

```
CREATE TABLE `myWords_table` (
    `myWords` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`myWords`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

***SQL:***

```
INSERT INTO myWords_table (myWords) VALUES ("word"),("Word")

ALSO to better show:

 INSERT INTO myWords_table (myWords) VALUES ("word"),("WORD")

Error: Duplicate entry 'word' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

*I also tried Unique Key.
It seems like MYSQL can not handle capital vs Small

Can you please help me?*

Status UPDATE

The ERROR is not the space, it is Capital and small letters.

Comment: Cannot recreate your case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b162/2/0

Comment: Is that exactly what your SQL query reads when exectuted? You're not running the variables through a sanitising function first that's removing extra whitespace?

Comment: Are you sure you are not executing the insert statement twice, and/or there is no row with those values prior to the insert? @lad2025 looks like you discovered a bug with fiddle output, as it loses the extra space in the row output.

Comment: @JRD This is not the bug, whitespaces like tab or newline are not displayed also. See also [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384684). If you think it is bug not feature feel free to inform SQLFiddle/SEDE creators :)

Comment: Perhaps, depending on how you look at it, its a bug/feature. It is not displaying the value that is in the db, and that is something to be aware of.

Comment: @JRD I would say feature. If you have newline characters then each row may have different height. Anyway good to be aware of it

Comment: Status UPDATE: The Problem what mysql says was wrong. It is because one letter is small and the other is big: ("Word"),("word") Any Ideas?

Comment: @JRD If you use DevTools (FF, Chrome, other) in SQL Fiddle or SEDE see that the blanks are there, but when the page is rendering are removed.

Comment: Change the collation of your table, for example: `COLLATE = 'utf8_bin'`. See [10.1.7.1 Collation Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-names.html).

Comment: @wchiquito i changed it to utf8_bin, but this doesnt solved the problem

Comment: @wchiquito i can't open your fiddle demo. MSG Something went wrong..

Comment: See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e1c7f/1).

Comment: @wchiquito Thank you for your post, I Looked up into mysql workbench thats the create code. Do you see the mistake?
`
CREATE TABLE `myWords_table` (
  `myWords` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myWords`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Comment: See new [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ba086/1).

Comment: @wchiquito I tried to change like Jimmy said on the answer down the page. But mysql workbench log says "No changes detected" Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Jimmy for this answer and everybody who helps me.

MYSQL bad MYSQL Workbench.

RUN THIS SQL:

```
alter table myWords_table change column myWords myWords varchar(250) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

ANY Ideas how to prevent for future against this?

Jimmys answer: 
You can set the database's collation to utf8_bin to start with, and then any created table use the default collation will inherit that collation

Thank you all for this great work. You helped me so much!!

Greeces,

Sebstian

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but just how encoding and mysql works. It all depends on what encodings you are using for your Key column, some encodings are case sensitive and some others aren't. In your case, utf8_general_ci it's not Case Sensitive, meaning that for comparison purposes, word = WORD = WoRd = ...

If you use the utf8_bin encoding you shouldn't find that behaviour. As per the following script

```
CREATE TABLE `myWords_table` (
    `myWords` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`myWords`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.80 sec)

INSERT INTO myWords_table (myWords) VALUES ("word"),("Word");
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.09 sec)

select * from myWords_table;
+---------+
| myWords |
+---------+
| Word    |
| word    |
+---------+
```

As opposed, when you use utf8_general_ci

```
CREATE TABLE `myWords_table` (
    `myWords` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`myWords`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.37 sec)

INSERT INTO myWords_table (myWords) VALUES ("word"),("Word");
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Word' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: No this is wrong.

I changed my encoding to utf8_bin and entered my SQL from above, still have this problem.

CREATE TABLE `myWords_table` (
    `myWords` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`myWords`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: I believe you aren't testing this properly, and I'm fairly confident that it's your issue. I just tested it and it works as I said.

Comment: I looked up int MYSQL WOrkbench, thats the create code

CREATE TABLE `myWords_table` (
  `myWords` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myWords`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Comment: There are two collations involved in your query, the TABLE collation and the COLUMN collation. In your case you are setting the TABLE collation to utf8_bin, and the COLUMN collation to utf8, which defaults to the standard collation (which it's utf8_general_ci I think). In WorkBench select the column "myWords" and then, below where your can see it's details, chose the collation for that column as utf8_bin. Not the table's collation.
CREATE TABLE myWords_table ( myWords varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, ...

Comment: I try to change it. I go on my table, there stands Collation: utf -utf8_bin . Then i click on myWords and on details there is utf8 - default collation , than i click on the drop down and choose utf -utf8_bin . Press Apply and i got on the Log No changes detected.

I tried than my Insert and it doesnt work. Any Ideas?

Comment: MySQL WorkBench has it's flaws. You can use the alter directly, run the following query: alter table myWords_table change column myWords myWords varchar(250) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

Comment: I tried to update DB with SQL:

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `test`.`myWords_table` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `myWords` `myWords` VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET 'utf8_bin' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL COMMENT '' ,
DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ERROR 1115: Unknown character set: 'utf8_bin'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `test`.`myWords_table`
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `myWords` `myWords` VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET 'utf8_bin' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL COMMENT '' ,
DROP PRIMARY KEY

Comment: any Ideas how to prevent of this bug. I mean for future databases.

Comment: You can set the database's collation to utf8_bin to start with, and then any created table use the *default collation* will inherit that collation.